# Jquery Div slide downa down and bounce animation effect

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to combine two jquery show effects: bounce and slidedown.

My original slide down animation is as follows:

```
$('#mydiv').slideDown( 100, function() {});
```

and the bounce animation

```
( "bounce", { times: 3 }, "slow" );
```

I want the div to slide down and bounce a little like that of Tumblr when you click on upload photo

Answer (score 0):

what you are wanting is easily done with a queue...

```
<script>
$( "#show" ).click(function() {
  var n = jQuery.queue( $( "div" )[ 0 ], "fx" );
  $( "span" ).text( "Queue length is: " + n.length );
});

function runIt() {
  $( "div" )
    .show( "slow" )
    .animate({
      left: "+=200"
    }, 2000 )
    .slideToggle( 1000 )
    .slideToggle( "fast" )
    .animate({
      left: "-=200"
    }, 1500 )
    .hide( "slow" )
    .show( 1200 )
    .slideUp( "normal", runIt );
}

runIt();
</script>
```

Something like the above... copied from the link below.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.queue/

Comment: i'm trying to do this without a queue. Preferably by chaining the functions together.